# rectangles, lines draw on canvas along with undo & redo operations

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I need to draw rectangles & lines on canvas, along with this elements need to perform undo & redo operations. It is working fine for sketch, but am fail at rectangle & lines point of view. If any one know please share the code.
thanks in advance.

For this i have take array & push my drawing context to it. like that am performed undo & redo operations.

```
function cPush() { 
    cStep++;
    if (cStep < cPushArray.length {
        cPushArray.length = cStep;
    }
    cPushArray.push(document.getElementById('imageView').toDataURL());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your current work (not all of it, just the important lines!) and give a more detailed explaination.

Comment: function cPush() {
cStep++;
if (cStep < cPushArray.length) {
cPushArray.length = cStep;
}
cPushArray.push(document.getElementById('imageView').toDataURL());
}

Comment: Saving your history with .toDataURL is the least efficient way of saving because the entire canvas is converted to an image url. Instead, to Undo, save the users drawing commands in an array, pop() the last command off the array and redraw all the remaining commands.